# Cannot generate Histogram in gnuplot "all points y value undefined"

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

So I have my .dat file which contain values as follow

```
d1 428
d2 412
d3 404
d4 433
d5 421
d6 402
d1 424
d2 440
d3 416
d4 394
d5 413
...
```

also, have my .sh file for gnuplot

```
reset
n = 1
max = 10.
min = 0.
width = (max-min)/n
hist(x,width) = width*floor(x/width) + width/2.0

set xrange[max:min]
set yrange [0:]

set term png 
set output "histogram.png"

set boxwidth width*0.5
set style fill solid 0.5
set tics out nomirror

set xlabel "Valor dado"
set ylabel "Frecuencia"


plot "dice.dat" u (hist($1,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "red" notitle
```

but gnuplot said "all points y value undefined!"
so my questions is if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong, aside from why it is wrong.
I know you may have help other people whit this kind of issue, but i don't have any idea of what is happening and I would like to understand, so if someone if kindhearted enough to help me i will be very thankful

Answer (score 1):

Deducing from your definition of the `hist` function, `width` is the width of the bins, and you must not set the xrange to `[min:max]`, because you use these values only to define a single bin. Another thing is, that gnuplot's column counting starts at `1`, and the numerical values are in the second column so you must use `hist($2, width)`.

A working minimal script is then

```
reset
width = 10.0
hist(x,width) = width*floor(x/width) + width/2.0

set yrange [0:*]

set boxwidth 0.5 relative
set style fill solid 0.5

plot "dice.dat" u (hist($2,width)):(1.0) smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "red" notitle
```